# Switching between arrays to produce a label.text

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Let’s say I have 2 arrays set up like this:

`let fooArray = [“Dog”, “Cat”, “Fox”]`

`let barArray = [“Cow”, “Duck”, “Sheep”]`

I also have a UILabel which changes its text based on other UI button’s sender tags set up as follows:

`Label.text = fooArray[sender.tag-1]`

I want to make another button which will change the Label.text to whatever is in the barArray with the same current position of the fooArray so for example if:

`Label.text = fooArray[5]`

I want the button to do:

`Label.text = barArray[5]`

The theory I came up with was to create a variable which is a string of whatever is in Label.text, search the fooArray for the position of that string, use that position to specify what goes in the brackets of:

`Label.text = barArray[HERE]`

That seems a bit cumbersome and it feels like there should be a more elegant solution, am I missing something here?

Comment: As you are talking about *a bit cumbersome*: two separate arrays are pretty cumbersome. A struct containing both values respectively is more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
if let index = fooArray.firstIndex(of:label.text!) {
   label.text = barArray[index]
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. If I wanted to then click on the button to revert the change, what would I add?
This is the code so far:

`@IBAction func advancedLabelPressed(_ sender: AnyObject)` 

`{ if let index = advancedWordArray.firstIndex(of:advancedPracticeLabel.text!) {
            advancedPracticeLabel.text = altadvancedWordArray[index]
        }
    }`